# ObjectAnimator not working properly when view.getX() != 0

Tags: java, android, view, objectanimator

I'm using ObjectAnimator to translate a view horizontally to the right edge of the outer view. Both views are children of the same layout, with the second view matching width and height of the parent and enclosing the first view. When my activity starts and ObjectAnimator is called to translate the view, it will only end up at the correct destination when the view starts out at 0.0, 0.0. When start coordinates are 100.00,100.00 , the view ends up 100.00 units past where it's supposed to be.

```
startX = view.getX();
        endX = getRight(layout) - view.getWidth();
        Log.i("debugger", "going from  x="+startX+" to x="+endX);
        translateRight = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", startX, endX);
```

And in the animatorListener

```
@Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            Log.i("debugger", "end x = "+view.getX());
        }
```

The method I use to get the X coordinate of the right edge of a view

```
public int getRight(View view){
    return (int)(view.getX()+view.getWidth());
}
```

Snippet of xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="82"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/outerView"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_height="@dimen/view_width"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/view_width"
            android:background="@drawable/view"
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/obstacle1"
            android:layout_below="@id/obstacle1"
            />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/obstacle1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/view_width"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/view_width"
            android:background="@drawable/obstacle"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />
```

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Emkd.png)

When the view starts off in the upper left hand corner (where obstacle 1 is), the view ends up flush against the inside right wall of the outerView, where it should be. However, when the view has non-zero coordinates, as in the example where it sits below and to the right of obstacle1, it goes past the right edge and sits flush against the outside wall of the outerView. The funny thing is, if the view is placed in the xml at the upper left hand corner, it can move as supposed to no matter where it becomes positioned. When it doesn't start in the corner, everything's jacked from the get-go.

The logs look as follows for when view starts at 0,0:

```
going from x=0 to x=1080
end x = 1080
```

The logs look as follows for when view starts at 100, 100:

```
going from x=100 to x=1080
end x = 1180
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are translating the view on the X axe, with start value 100. If the translationX attribute of your view is 0, then the animation will start by instantly translating your view by 100.

You should do something like this :

```
translateRight = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", view.getTranslationX(), endX - startX);
```

Comment: I tried using your example and it works for the first translation, but if I translate right again, it goes back the other direction instead of not moving at all(because it's already against the wall).

Comment: Well, add some checking to move only when needed ;-)

Comment: Why is it that the view has to start at 0,0 for this to work? Im using this in a game to move the view into obstacles and I can swipe it around all day if it starts in the corner, but if the movable view starts anywhere else, it bugs out.

Comment: Because you are modifying the translateX attribute, not the X attribute. If you want to move the X attribute, then change the second parameter of your animator, from "translateX" to "X"

Comment: Wow I can't believe I was mixing the two up this whole time. Thank you very much.